# Dear Family & Friends or Dear Friends & Family?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

I would like to begin the speach adressing family & friends...

Should I say " Dear Family & Friends " or " Dear Friends & Family "?

Comment: Which are more important to you: your family, or your friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I heard "family and friends" then I would interpret it as "family and (other) friends". On the other hand, "friends and family" implies "friends and those people who I do not like but who are here only because of a blood relationship or marriage".

Only you can decide which meaning one you intend, but I suggest that the first is less likely to cause offence.

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S., I'd probably avoid "friends and family" only because a certain phone company soiled that phrase by making it the name of a marketing campaign. Reversing it to "Family and Friends" escapes that association.